# PF10 in atmel ATxmegaxxxA1U

Tags: atmel, xmega, atxmega

[Atmel AVR1916: USB DFU Boot Loader for XMEGA  application note](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8429.pdf) reports that for the ATxmegaxxxA1U the pin for starting the programming is PF10, but the devices has no such pin, as shown in the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8385-8-and-16-bit-avr-microcontroller-atxmega64a1u-atxmega128a1u_datasheet.pdf).

On the web the problem is highlighted [here](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=130984) and [here](http://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/313685) but no answer is given.

In particular, the last link reports that PF0 did not work.Code for other devices have a match between the ISP_PORT_PINCTRL and ISP_PORT_PIN   (5 and 5, 3 and 3, ...) 
but A1U seems not to.

```
00068 #if XMEGA_A1U
00069 # define ISP_PORT_DIR      PORTF_DIR
00070 # define ISP_PORT_PINCTRL  PORTF_PIN5CTRL
00071 # define ISP_PORT_IN       PORTF_IN
00072 # define ISP_PORT_PIN      0
00073 #elif (XMEGA_A3U || XMEGA_A3BU)
00074 # define ISP_PORT_DIR      PORTE_DIR
00075 # define ISP_PORT_PINCTRL  PORTE_PIN5CTRL
00076 # define ISP_PORT_IN       PORTE_IN
00077 # define ISP_PORT_PIN      5
00078 #elif XMEGA_A4U
00079 # define ISP_PORT_DIR      PORTC_DIR
00080 # define ISP_PORT_PINCTRL  PORTC_PIN3CTRL
00081 # define ISP_PORT_IN       PORTC_IN
00082 # define ISP_PORT_PIN      3
00083 #elif XMEGA_B
00084 # define ISP_PORT_DIR      PORTC_DIR
00085 # define ISP_PORT_PINCTRL  PORTC_PIN6CTRL
00086 # define ISP_PORT_IN       PORTC_IN
00087 # define ISP_PORT_PIN      6
00088 #else
00089 # error Unknow AVR Xmega part
00090 #endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo. In conf_isp.h the ISP port pin is defined as 0, not 10.

```
// Definition of hardware condition to enter in ISP mode
#if XMEGA_A1
# define ISP_PORT_DIR      PORTF_DIR
# define ISP_PORT_PINCTRL  PORTF_PIN5CTRL
# define ISP_PORT_IN       PORTF_IN
# define ISP_PORT_PIN      0
```

ETA: 
But even that doesn't match the pinout diagram in the datasheet, which says PDI_DATA = PORT Q pin 89. This is the pin used on the [MT-X1S ATxmega128a1(u)dev board](http://www.mattairtech.com/index.php/development-boards/mt-x1s-atxmega128a1-u-usb-development-board.html) by Mattairtech.

I have no idea how it is supposed to work when the source code references a different pin. We can only hope that the actual firmware supplied in the chips is correct...

Comment: I commented in the reply because here it was too long